# How to use model functions in view in django?

Tags: django

let's say I define a function in my model to return a formatted value like:

```
def formatMoney(self):
  return '$' + self.money
```

How can I use this on my view?

Well I guess I expressed myself poorly. I'm trying to use it on the template file not in the view class as I'm iterating in the template file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call the function from the instance of your model, same way you would call a function on an instance outside of a view.

```
# views.py

def your_view(request):
    instance = YourModel.objects.get(pk=234)
    instance.formatMoney()
    render(request, 'your_template.html', {'instance': instance})

# your_template.html
  {{ instance.formatMoney }}
```

To call methods inside of djangos template language, omit the `()`

Comment: Sorry, I added more info to my question, and now that I searched for template instead of view I found answers, thank you.

Comment: Hi, how do it with queryset? For example, I want to use `get_member_rating` then order_by `member_rating` in queryset on views